# Insert element bootstrap in div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to insert html tag using javascript but it is not working because of the quotes.

the .text working only in the variable, but innerHTML does not work.

```
$("#year_title").text(response[0]['year_title']);
document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = '<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%"></div>
</div>';
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the html code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that the two newlines are the problem:

```js
document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = '<div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">Hello</div></div>';
```

```html
<div id="progress">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is that you can't span single(') or double(") quote strings over multiple lines. You can overcome this problem in 4 ways:

1. Create your string in single line using single(') or double(") quotes.

```js
document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = '<div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">Hello World</div></div>';
```

```html
<div id="progress">
</div>
```

2. Join multiple string using concatenation(+) operator:

```js
    document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = '<div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">'+
    'Hello World'+
    '</div>'+
    '</div>';
```

```html
<div id="progress">
</div>
```

3. Make single(') or double(") quotes string span multiple lines by escaping newline character using backslash()

```js
document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = '<div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">\
    Hello World\
    </div>\
    </div>';
```

```html
<div id="progress">
</div>
```

4. Use ES6 style multiline strings using backticks(`):

Check out this snippet:

```js
document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = `<div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">Hello World
  </div>
    </div>`;
```

```html
<div id="progress">
</div>
```